# why is my list cannot be convert into zip list? python

Tags: python, html, django

i have 2 list that i got from input in my html
i want to ouput that 2 list together
but when i use zip(lista, listb)
no output shown

```
         {% for proc, ope in procslist %}
          <tr>
            <td style="width:10%;">{{proc.id}}</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">{{proc.name}}</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">{{proc.setcost}} / {{proc.proccost}}</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">{{proc.id}}</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">{{proc.id}}</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">{{proc.id}}</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">{{proc.settime}}</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">
              <input type="hidden" name="opetimelist" value="{{proc.id}}" id="">
              <input type="text" name="opetime-{{proc.id}}" id="" value="{{ope}}"
              style="width: 80%;">
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

and this is my views.py

```
        proc = ''
        choosenproc = request.POST.get('choosenproc')
        if choosenproc:
            proc = Proc.objects.get(Q(name__icontains=choosenproc) | Q(id__icontains=choosenproc))

            flag = False
            if proc:
                if selectedproc != []:
                    for product in selectedproc:
                        if product.id == proc.id:
                            flag = True
                            break
                if flag == False:
                    selectedproc.append(proc)
        
        opetimelist = request.POST.getlist('opetimelist')
        opetimevalue = [request.POST['opetime-{}'.format(o)] for o in opetimelist]
        
        procslist = zip(selectedproc, opetimevalue)
```

the result it no ouput

how to fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by no output, where you using that in code?

Comment: Did you add your procslist to context?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.